# Perl win32::GUI thread

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have written a script to connect to a host system and run some commands using the Win32::GUI module for entering commands.

While it is in progress, the GUI freezes and is unresponsive until it is complete.

Could anyone tell me how to implement thread for this scenario.

Comment: You need to show some code here...

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
```

`use warnings;use Net::Telnet;`
`use Win32::API;
use Win32::GUI();`

```
my $main = Win32::GUI::Window->new(
  -name => 'Main',
  -width => 500,
  -height => 900,
  -text => 'Perl',
  -minsize => 500, 900,
  );

my $font = Win32::GUI::Font->new( -name => "Comic Sans MS", -size => 8,);
$main->AddLabel(-text => "Welcome ", -pos  => [ 10, 10 ],);
$main->AddLabel(-text => "Enter Host Name / IP : ", -pos  => [ 10, 33 ],  );
my $t= $main->AddTextfield( -name => 'tfResults', -text => "", -pos  => [ 125, 30 ],  -size => [ 100, 25 ], -tabstop => 1, );
my $my_but = $main->AddButton(-text => "Submit",-name => 'btQuery', -pos  => [ 235, 30 ],-size => [ 50, 25 ],);
$main->Show(); 
Win32::GUI::Dialog();

sub btQuery_Click 
{

  my $txt1=$t->Text;  
  my $telnet = new Net::Telnet (   Timeout=>1800,    Errmode=>'die',    ); 
  chomp $txt1; 
  $telnet->open($txt1);

  $telnet->waitfor('/login: $/i');
  $telnet->print('root');
  $telnet->waitfor('/Password: $/i');
  $telnet->print('dangerous');
  $telnet->waitfor('/# $/i');
  print "\nConnected to host :$txt1 ";

  $main->AddLabel(-text => " Enter custom cmd:",-pos => 100, 100 ,-size => 250, 125 ,);
  my $t1= $main->AddTextfield(-name => 'tfResults2',-text => "",-pos => 130, 100 ,-size => 100, 25 ,);
  my $submit=$main->AddButton(-text => "Submit",-name => 'Unix_submit',-pos => 250, 100 ,-size => 50, 25 ,);



sub Unix_submit_Click { }

   } `
```